# How to change (Joomla) admin layout of subforms from table mode to div mode?

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to change the admin table view of subforms in Joomla 3.9.13 (backend) to the (already existing) div mode.
I can manage to do this by changing the code in:

plugins/fields/repeatable/repeatable.php line 52

Changing:

```
$fieldNode->setAttribute('layout', 'joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table');
```

To:

```
$fieldNode->setAttribute('layout', 'joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable');
```

This is a core modification. So how can I achieve this without modifying the core file(s)?

Comment: You can override the repeatable table layout with the code from the default layout.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I could create an override in /<my_template>/html/layouts/joomla/field/subform.
I put the file repeatable-table.php and folder repeatable-table in it. I changed the contents to the repeatable ones, but nothing happens.. This is the right way to override it, right?

Comment: Did you also override the files inside `layouts/joomla/field/subform/repeatable-table/`?

Comment: @Lodder no. I did it in my template in: "/<my_template>/html/layouts/joomla/field/subform" And that should have worked, right? Isn't overriding the files in main layout folder same as overriding core files? Thx for your quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lodder suggested, you can override the repeatable-table layout with the code from the repeatable layout. The reason why it does not work for you is because you override files in your frontend template instead of the backend template.

If you put your overrides in:

```
/administrator/templates/isis/html/layouts/joomla/field/subform
```

They should work as expected (I assume the Isis is your default backend template).

Answer (score 2):

There is a default function of the sub-form field type that allows you to select a layout.

> **layout** (optional) the name of the layout to use when displaying subform fields. Available layouts:
>
> **joomla.form.field.subform.default** render the subform in a div container, without support of repeating. Default for single mode.
>
> **joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable** render the subform in a div container, used for multiple mode. Support groupByFieldset.
>
> **joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table** render the subform as a table, used for multiple mode. Supports groupByFieldset. By default each field is rendered as a table column, but if groupByFieldset=true then each fieldset is rendered as a table column.

You will need to update this in the form xml file which can be found in /models/forms/viewname.xml

```
<field
    name="field-name"
    type="subform"
    label="Subform Field"
    layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable"
/>
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don't think this is the answer to this question. But to be sure, where should this XML file be? I couldn't find any /model/forms/... for the repeatable you can create within Joomla custom fields.